# Why does the separatrix in phase portraits have infinite period and pass through at least one unstable equillibrium point?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems

In the case of 1D Hamiltonians not explicitely dependent on time, our professor claims that the "period" of the separatrix is necessarily infinite and must pass through an unsable equilibrium or connect two such points. Although I can kind of see the hand-wavy argument, I don't understand how to prove it.

I think we are supposed to use the connection between the curve area and energy, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: If you want to prove something like this, you need a precise definition of separatrix.  Some authors would say that a separatrix is a curve which meets a hyperbolic (unstable) fixed point, in which case the proof is simply in the definition.  Assuming this is *not* the case for you, what definition are you starting from?

Comment: @J.Murray I'm starting from this: separatrices are curves that seperate classes of paths with different topological properties